# How to index a list of LSTMStateTuple with a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have a python list of `LSTMStateTuple` objects and I have to use a tensor as index to retrieve them. For example:

```
index = tf.constant(0)
lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(128)
states = [lstm.zero_state(10, tf.float32), lstm.zero_state(10, tf.float32)]
```

If I try `state = states[index]` I get an error and `state = tf.gather(states, index)` converts `states` in a tensor and returns a tensor of shape `[10, 2, 128]`.

How can I get a `LSTMStateTuple` instead of a tensor? I would like to avoid the conversions from list of `LSTMStateTuple` to tensor and from tensor to `LSTMStateTuple` when I pass to the lstm the state.

Comment: `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMStateTuple

Answer (score 0):

You create two states and put them in a `LSTMStateTuple`.

```
cell_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, state_size])
hidden_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, state_size])
init_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(cell_state, hidden_state)
```